# Android build issues with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I have a cordova android app that I am trying to build with android version 8.1.0.

While I attempt build, I see the below error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib] C:\Users\Thejwal\Desktop\IES.InMotion.Driver_10_22_2018_V0.5\IES.InMotion.Driver\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

After checking out a number of threads describing the same issue, I could see that the issue seems to be with the minsdkvalue.

I can see the below in the platforms/android/build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.3" //String
      **defaultMinSdkVersion**=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}
```

There is another build.gradle in the app folder. I cant see any minsdkversion there.

Can somebody please help me to understand what the error message means and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to override your manifest using, in config.xml

```
   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
   <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```